# How can I hold an adjustable angle between two load-bearing plates?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, steel

I have two wooden plates with the same dimensions (5 cm thick, 50 cm long and 35 cm wide).

[image: sketch of plate orientation]

The distance between plates must be at least 10 cm. Plate P<sub>1</sub> is fixed but P<sub>2</sub> rotates about the y-axis. Angle alpha can go from 0 degrees (when the plates are parallel) to at least 90 degrees.

[image: sketch of distance between plates]

How can I realize this design in practice? Which mechanical elements should I use? It must be strong, there will be load of max. 30 kg hanging on plate P<sub>2</sub>. There must be some mechanism that will connect these two plates and enable P<sub>2</sub> to rotate but when one sets a desired angle between plates, the mechanism must hold the angle constant.

[image: sketch of angle between plates]

Comment: My first thought is a [positioning hinge](http://www.southco.com/en-us/product/hierarchy.html?hid=8162&filters=) or [friction hinge.](http://frictionhinge.com/)

Comment: Or a strut to hold the cantilevered load.

Answer (score 3):

My First thought is to use a standard hinge, with the hinge itself on the intersecting lines. The plates can mounted with an offset to create your desired gap.  Secondly, you need a positioning mechanism. You can use a rotary detent mechanism, for example two disks with radial grooves that interlock in each other when bolted together and can rotate when the bolt is loosened up.

I would not choose a friction mechanism at the rotation axis. The load is large, which creates a strong moment.

Answer (score -1):

I think that easiest way to solve the problem of rotating of plate P<sub>2</sub> will be using a mechanism like this:

[image: hinge mechanism]

To use it, join plate P<sub>1</sub> to an additional plate with length of 10 cm (height and width depends on the dimensions of mechanism) like this:

[image: sketch of additional plate]

After join of "unknown element" with P1 and after placing P2 on "unknown element", construction will look like this:

[image: sketch of linkage between plates]

I still need to find way to prevent plate P<sub>2</sub> from falling, I don't think that screws will be enough to attach this mechanism to the plates.

Comment: I agree with your general idea, but it might be better to find a hinge more suited to your application.  Something that works more like a GoPro mount hinge, e.g. http://www.bluewaterphotostore.com/sites/default/files/gopro-front-mount.jpg